# Is an interface can be used for common methods between class?

Tags: c#, methods, interface

I want to have a common method between many classes to do some tasks. It work but I'm not sure it's acceptable.. Example of 2 classes which implement the interface with the freeView() method:

```
class BrowserView : ChromiumWebBrowser, IView
    {
        public void freeView()
        {
            // Some work
        }
    }

class VideoView : Canvas, IView
{
    public void freeView()
    {
        // Some work
    }
}`
```

And i call the method like that in my main module :

```
private object activeView =  null; 
            switch (settings.vue)
            {
                case Vue.Website:
                    activeView = new BrowserView(this, settings.sourcePath);
                    gridView.Children.Add(activeView as BrowserView);
                    break;
                case Vue.Video:
                    activeView = new VideoView(this, settings.sourcePath);
                    gridView.Children.Add(activeView as VideoView);
                    break;
            }
```

And when i need to call the freeView() method, i cast activeView like that

```
private void deleteView()
{
    if(activeView != null)
    {
        ((IView)activeView).freeView();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the method has the same implementation you can use inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage of interface is correct. However, you should use `IView` interface reference instead of `object` in your client to avoid casting:

```
private IView activeView = null; 
// ...
activeView.freeView(); // No casting here!
```

You can also add one more `IView` implementation that does nothing (`null object` pattern) to avoid `null` check in your code:

```
switch (settings.vue)
{
    case Vue.Website:
        // ...
    case Vue.Video:
        // ...
    default:
        activeView = new EmptyView();
}
```

So in your client code you can just omit `if(activeView != null)` nulltiy check.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely acceptable.  I would only advise you to change the type of activeView from object to IView.  In this way you don't have to cast it to perform most operations common to both.

Just be sure that the *meanings* between these methods remains the same.  If you're having generic methods like "execute" in IView, you should rethink your strategy.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you are implementing a interface `IView` to your class it means you are adding a View behaviour to your class. Which ever classes which implement `IView` makes the promise it will have this behaviour.

So yes an interface can be created specifically for common methods between classes, when you want to access only that particular behaviour.

Make sure you declare - `gridView.Children` as `List<IView>` or whatever. Then you can do this directly.

```
activeView = new BrowserView(this, settings.sourcePath);
gridView.Children.Add(activeView);
```

Then you can access IView methods as it is. For e.g.

```
foreach(var child gridView.Children)
{
  child.FreeView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make interfaces based on concepts not because you need to group couple of methods across classes. For instance an interface such as `IActivatableView` is more sensible and understandable to clients than `IView`. You can multiple interfaces to represent different concepts. Once again technically what you are doing is right but from a design point of view, what I am suggesting might be better.